# get an html element do something and append result back to that element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to build a music player. now I am getting link of each song, generating its wave, and then printing the wave back to that song. wave is printing in `<div class="wavetest"></div>`. here is the HTML code

```
<div class="playlist p-5">
  <div class="song p-3">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span><button href="song.mp3" class="songlink btn"> song 1<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="wavetest">here wave should be of song 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span><button href="song2.m4a" class="songlink btn"> song 2<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="wavetest">here wave should be of song 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <span><button href="song3.mp3" class="songlink btn"> song 3<i class="fa fa-play playbtn"></i></button></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="wavetest">here wave should be of song 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var links_arr = [];
        $('.playlist button').each(function () {
          links_arr.push( $(this).attr("href") );
        });
          for (i = 0; i < links_arr.length; ++i) {
            var link = links_arr[i];
              var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                container: '.wavetest', //container where wave will be printed
                waveColor: 'violet',
                progressColor: 'purple'
            });
              wavesurfer.load(link); //generating wave for given song 
          }

    });
```

now I am getting the wave of all three songs in first `<div class="wavetest"></div>`. I want to get the wave in its appropriate div. how can I tackle it and suggest if there is any better of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Container can be a DOM element](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/), so you can pass each `wavetest` to each `WaveSurfer.create`. Let me know if this works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var links_arr = [];

    $('.playlist .row').each(function () {
        const link = $(this).find('button').attr("href");
        const waveContainer = $(this).find('.wavetest');

        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          // https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/ says container can be a DOM element
          // waveContainer is a jQuery object, waveContainer[0] to get actually DOM element
          container: waveContainer[0],
          waveColor: 'violet',
          progressColor: 'purple'
        });
        wavesurfer.load(link); //generating wave for given song 
    });
});
```

Comment: I have just copy-pasted your code and I'm getting an error " can you please guide me where changes are needed

Comment: error is : container element is not found

Comment: Answer updated, I should use `find` instead of `children`.

Comment: thanks alot,  got it